# Java: Is it possible to add / attach a proxy to a live object instance during runtime?

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, javassist

I know Java supports proxies. I've been checking Javassist but not sure whether it can support the following trick:

```
public class Hello {

    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

Hello hello = new Hello();

Hello proxyHello = createProxy(hello);
proxyHello.hi(); // method will be intercepted by a predefined proxy
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is available in the JDK only allows to create proxies that implement a set of interfaces, if you want to create a proxy of a `Class`, you will need to use `Javassist` but to be able to do it you need a constructor that is accessible from the class where you create your proxy.

**Here is a way to implement what you need:**

```
final Hello hello = new Hello() {
    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
};
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(Hello.class);
MethodHandler handler = (self, m, proceed, args) -> {
    // This allows to proxy even non accessible methods, it could not be
    // needed depending on your context
    if (!m.isAccessible())
        m.setAccessible(true);
    return m.invoke(hello, args);
};
Hello proxy = (Hello)factory.create(new Class<?>[0], new Object[0], handler);
proxy.hi();
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
```

In this example:

1. First I create my factory
2. Then I provide the super class
3. Then I define how to handle all method calls on the proxy *(here I delegate everything to my live object)*
4. Finally I create my proxy *(here I use the default constructor to create the proxy).*

More details [here](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/util/proxy/ProxyFactory.html)

Assuming that you have a constructor with one `String` argument you will need to modify the last line as next:

```
Hello proxy = (Hello)factory.create(
    new Class<?>[]{String.class}, new Object[]{"bar"}, handler
);
```

Here I call a constructor with one argument of type `String` and I provided `bar` as value.

Comment: Nice Nicolas! But this will only work for the simple case of a default constructor, in other words, if my class takes only a zero argument constructor. If I have created my object through a different constructor I'll be in trouble!

Comment: No you will only need to modify the argument of the create method of the factory

Comment: @PikaSucar I updated my answer to give you a concrete example

Comment: That breaks my requirement. When I give you an instance you have no way of knowing with which constructor it was created, agree?

Comment: @PikaSucar maybe but we don't care actually as we delegate every method calls to your live object, we only need to be able to create the proxy that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to accomplish something like this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: No you can't my friend

Comment: Are you able to have ``Hello`` implement an interface?  If not then you're right, ``Proxy`` won't work for you.